# How to sort ordinal values in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Say i've got a field 'spicey' with possible values 'hot', 'hotter', 'smoking'.

There's an intrinsic ordening in these values: they're ordinals.

I'd like to be able to sort or filter on them using their intrinsic order. For example: give me all documents where spicey > hot.

Sure i can translate the values to integers 0,1,2 but this requires extra housekeeping on both the index and the query side which I'd rather avoid.

Is this possible in some way? Already contemplated using multi field mapping but not sure if that would help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort based on string values by scripting a sort operation, so that you set each spicey string a specific field value.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/yourindex/yourtype/_search' -d 
{
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "script": "factor.get(doc[\"spicey\"].value)",
      "type": "number",
      "params": {
        "factor": {
          "hot": 0,
          "hotter": 1,
          "smoking": 2
        }
      },
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm not clear from the question headline , but I need filtering too. Ie.: show all docs where spicey > hot. Any way to do this?

Comment: I had various problems with making ES 5.4 abide with this query. My two cents:
`  "sort" : [ {
    "_script" : {
      "script" : {
        "inline" : "return params.channelOrder.getOrDefault(String.valueOf(doc['channelId'].value), 2147483647);",
        "params" : {
          "channelOrder" : {
            "4" : 1,
            "2" : 2,
            "3" : 3,
            "null" : 2147483647
          }
        }
      },
      "type" : "number",
      "order" : "asc"
    }}, {
    "_score" : {
      "order" : "desc"
    }}, {
    "_uid" : {
      "order" : "desc"
    }} ]`

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be to create a specific analyzer for spice levels. The idea is to map each level to a discrete value which increases the more spicy the spice is.

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "spices": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "mild=>1",
            "hot=>2",
            "hotter=>3",
            "smoking=>4"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "spice_synonyms": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": "spices",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "standard"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "ordinal": {
      "properties": {
        "spicy": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "level": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "spice_synonyms"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the above index settings and mappings, the `spicy` field would contain the plain english word (`hot`, `mild`, etc) while the `spicy.level` field would contain a discrete value that you can then use in queries and sorting.

For instance, retrieving documents whose spice level is strictly bigger than `hot` and ordered in decreasing order (smoking first) could be done like this:

```
{
  "sort": {
    "spicy.level": "desc"
  },
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "spicy.level:>2"
    }
  }
}
```

or a `range` query would work, too

```
{
  "sort": {
    "spicy.level": "desc"
  },
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "spicy.level" {
        "gt": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Going with the other answer since it would allow me to query spicey > hot instead of spicey.level > 2

Comment: Just realized your solution solves filtering as well, while the other doesn't. Would be so much nicer if I could just do spicey > hot instead through..

Comment: Filtering is a plus indeed, and this solution doesn't use scripting at all (all the heavy lifting is done at indexing time), which might induce performance hits at runtime depending on the amount of data you have.