# Elasticsearch: How to map keywords to discrete values in a subfield?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have an index with a keyword field expressing ratings: A, A+,...
I'd like to map those values into a subfield as integers in order to apply decay function to it.
Example:

```
rating: A
rating.value: 1
```

I just wanted to check here what would be the smartest approach based on my requirements.
From my understanding, it can be done or

- through analyzer: [How to sort ordinal values in elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624194/how-to-sort-ordinal-values-in-elasticsearch)
- through ingestion pipeline: [Elasticsearch mapping: How to analyze or map to numeric fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56040670/elasticsearch-mapping-how-to-analyze-or-map-to-numeric-fields)

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for a well-researched question. Indeed, these are viable solutions in many cases. However, in your case the analyzer approach will produce a text value, which will require conversion in runtime. The pipeline will add an additional field to the source, which might or might not be needed (wastes space, but might speedup reindexing).

There is also an option with implementing it as a [runtime field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/runtime.html).

But my favorite would probably be generate it by a [script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/number.html#number-params) in the mapping:

```
PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "rating": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "rating_value": {
        "type": "long",
        "script": """
            def ratings = ['F', 'E', 'D', 'C-', 'C', 'C+', 'C++', 'B-', 'B', 'B+', 'B++', 'A-', 'A', 'A+', 'A++'];
            emit(ratings.indexOf(doc['rating'].value))
         """
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/_bulk?refresh
{"index": {}}
{"rating": "D"}
{"index": {}}
{"rating": "A++"}
{"index": {}}
{"rating": "B"}
{"index": {}}
{"rating": "B-"}
{"index": {}}
{"rating": "who knows"}

GET test/_search
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "rating_value": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```